# ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub - still request password at login after key pairing

Tags: bash, ssh, rhel

---

Hi,

I've to access frequently at my remote host, then I've follow ssh man page suggestions,but after key pairing successfully with remote host, at time ssh login remote host is still requesting password. Instead I'would expect to access directly to remote host. Below my commands and configurations. could someone suggest me if there is some wrong or more actions to perform for?

---

```
localhost:mongod:/var/lib/mongo $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remhost

mongod@remhost's password:
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'remhost'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

localhost:mongod:/var/lib/mongo $ ssh -q mongod@remhost 'echo -e "$(hostname) pleased to sare you as slave"'
mongod@remhost's password:
remhost pleased to sare you as slave
localhost:mongod:/var/lib/mongo $


.ssh/authorized_keys
---
remhost:mongod:/home/mongod $ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC .... IK0F3NHw== mongod@remhost


/etc/ssh/sshd_config
---
remhost:mongod:/home/mongod $   egrep -v '^#|^# ' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin without-password
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/libexec/openssh/getpubkey.sh
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
X11Forwarding yes
Banner /etc/default/sshdbanner
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160
```

---

thanks a lot for your collaboration,

Comment: Could you post the output of `ssh -v remhost` (from your localhost). Also could you check if there is a user-specific SSH config file `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: sure, see below. thanks!

Comment: localhost:mongod:/var/lib/mongo $ ssh -v remhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remhost [10.97.29.229] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3

Comment: debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent

Comment: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'remhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/known_hosts:36
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex

Comment: debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

Comment: debug1: Offering public key: /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/mongo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mongod@remhost's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Tue Oct 24 12:20:07 2017 from 10.107.20.249
remhost:mongod:/home/mongod $

Comment: i didn't get your last request :(

Comment: Could you run `ls -la ~/.ssh/` on your localhost to see if there is a user-specific config file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permissions on the `.ssh` directory and the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file (they should 0700 and 0600, respectively).  It may also be necessary to fix the the SELinux context with `restorecon -R .ssh`.